# Como eu consigo imprimir apenas os itens iguais de duas arrays no java script?

Tags: javascript

```
    let rs = require('readline-sync')

let numeroDePerguntas = 5

let listaDeNumerosJ1 = []

let listaDeNumerosJ2 = []

let jogador1 = rs.question('Qual o nome do jogador 1? ')

for(i = 0; i < numeroDePerguntas; i++){
    let numeros = rs.questionInt('Escolha um número de 1 a 10: ')
    listaDeNumerosJ1.push(numeros)
}

let jogador2 = rs.question('Qual o nome do jogador 2? ')

for(i = 0; i < numeroDePerguntas; i++){
    let numeros = rs.questionInt('Escolha um número de 1 a 10: ')
    listaDeNumerosJ2.push(numeros)
}
```

preciso dar um console.log que imprima apenas os numeros iguais da listas 'listaDeNumerosJ1' e 'listaDeNumerosJ2'

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar dois iteradores de Array aninhados, assim:

```
listaDeNumerosJ1.forEach(j1 => {console.log('Igual: '+listaDeNumerosJ2.filter(j2 => j1==j2))});
```

Ou assim:

```
listaDeNumerosJ1.forEach( j1 => {
  if(listaDeNumerosJ2.indexOf(j1)+1)
    console.log(`O número ${j1} está nos dois jogos`);
});
```

E conferir no console se são iguais.